what is the authenticity of this hadith?
Sunan al kubra al bayhaqi 3224:
https://shamela.ws/book/7861/3657#p1
٣٢٢٤ - أَخْبَرَنَاهُ أَبُو سَعْدٍ الْمَالِينِيُّ، أنبأ أَبُو أَحْمَدَ بْنُ عَدِيٍّ، أنبأ عُمَرُ بْنُ سِنَانٍ، ثنا عَبَّاسٌ الْخَلَّالُ، ثنا يَحْيَى بْنُ صَالِحٍ، ثنا حَفْصُ بْنُ عُمَرَ، ثنا صَالِحُ بْنُ حَسَّانَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ كَعْبٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ: " لَا بَأْسَ أَنْ يُقَلِّبَ الرَّجُلُ الْجَارِيَةَ إِذَا أَرَادَ أَنْ يَشْتَرِيَهَا وَيَنْظُرَ إِلَيْهَا مَا خَلَا عَوْرَتَهَا، وَعَوْرَتُهَا مَا بَيْنَ رُكْبَتِهَا إِلَى مَعْقِدِ إِزَارِهَا "
3224 - Abu Saad Al-Malini told us, Abu Ahmad bin Adiy told us, Omar bin Sinan told us, Abbas Al-Khalal told us, Yahya bin Salih told us, Hafs bin Omar told us. Salih bin Hassan told us, on the authority of Muhammad bin Ka’b, on the authority of Ibn Abbas, may God be pleased with him, who said: The Messenger of God, may God bless him and grant him peace, said: “There is no harm in a man aquiring a slave girl if he wants to buy her and look at her except her private parts. It goes from between her knees to the knot of her lower garment.”

Shaykh Albani said in his Ad-Dai'fah (https://shamela.ws/book/12762/694 | #424) that the Hadith is Mawd'u (fabricated)!

Thank you for your response
